# IE apply 2 filters on image AlphaImageLoader and alpha(opacity=60)

Tags: css, internet-explorer, filter

How can I apply 2 filters on a image, I apply one like this:

```
<img id="theId" width=20 height=21 style="filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='images/myimage.png', sizingMethod='scale');" src="images/myimage.png">
```

How to apply

> filter:alpha(opacity=60);

as well ? If I do:

```
<img id="theId" width=20 height=21 style="filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='images/myimage.png', sizingMethod='scale');alpha(opacity=60);" src="images/myimage.png">
```

It does not work.

I've found a solution working on all IE(7+) and browsers: put the img in a div and apply transparancy to the div:

```
<div id="DIVIMG_myimage" style="opacity:0.6;width:100%;filter:alpha(opacity=60);"><img id="IMG_share_icon" width=20 height=21 style="filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='myimage.png', sizingMethod='scale') ;" src="myimage.png"></div>
```

Then to change the image opacity, just have to change the div DIVIMG_myimage opacity...same result. :-)

Comment: You should add working solution as the answer and accept it.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the ; delimiter between two filters. Filters are delimited only by space symbol:

```
filter:
    progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='images/myimage.png', sizingMethod='scale')
    alpha(opacity = 60);
```

Be sure to activate hasLayout with zoom:1

Also the image path on alphaImageLoader should have absolute path.

I can see it's an old post, but might help other people who have the same problem and google this issue.

Answer (score 0):

filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='images/myimage.png', sizingMethod='scale');
filter: alpha(opacity = 60);

Comment: It does not work, I tried on IE7 and IE8: `style="opacity:0.6;filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='images/myimage.png', sizingMethod='scale'); filter: alpha(opacity = 60);"` It takes just the second one.

Comment: I think it's because if you apply AlphaImageLoader you can't also apply alpha(opacity